# Javascript form element id parentNode if not direct field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

When I click on a form field (for example a text INPUT) within a web page I need to know the id of the parent form. 
As long as the item is directly inside the form tag I use the

```
elements [x] .parentNode.id;
```

but the problem arises when the form element is contained, for example, into a div element inside the form. In this case the function returns the id of the parent div and not the form. 
I would need a function that always tell me which is the id of the parent form if the INPUT element in question is directly child of the form or content in div or other objects within the form tag.

In my case the issue is further complicated because within the same web page there are two forms with different id that contain two inputs with the same properties:

First form

```
<form action="seminario.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="formContatti-footer" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div class="form-footer-left">
   <input type="text" name="azienda" value="" id="azienda" class="inputText3" required="required"><br>
   </div>  
   <input type="image" src="images/btn-iscriviti.png" name="invia" class="invia-footer"><br><br>
</form>
```

Second into same page:

```
<form action="seminario.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="formContatti-2" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div class="form-footer-left">
   <input type="text" name="azienda" value="Your email here" id="azienda" class="inputText3" required="required"><br>
   </div>  
   <input type="image" src="images/btn-iscriviti.png" name="invia" class="invia-footer"><br><br>
</form>
```

In this case, i need to discriminate if the field with id "azienda" is clicked on first or on second form and $(elements[x]).parents('form').attr('id') return ever the id of first form element read in the webpage code.

Thanks

Comment: After the edit I'm not sure why my answer does not work for you? Can't you look at the `id` of the closest form and compare it to `formContatti-footer` ?

Comment: Because i make an document.querySelectorAll('form');, then with a for cycle control all elements of the forms to see if what I'm clicking is the one with the active focus (with another for into first one: for (x=0; x<elements.length; x++){), when I find a match I get out of the loop. In this case, i check for an element with id "azienda" but is the same in both the form and then whether I click on the first or the second, the cycle always ends the first time I find an item with the same id in a form, and then always the first

Answer (score 3):

Well, as much as I feel bad about using jQuery here, it *is* tagged and it *is* simpler with it - so:

```
$(elements[x]).closest("form").attr("id")
```

Should do the trick, closest finds the closest element up the tree that matches a given selector so we find the closest form and match it.

In native JavaScript, you could do something like:

```
 var el = elements[x];
 while(el.parentNode.tagName !== "FORM") el = el.parentNode
 el.parentNode.id; // will find the form's id
```

Comment: Thanks, this work if the input id is different for the 2 forms in my page. In my case, i have the first form with id form-contact and the second form-news. Inside the forms there is an INPUT field with id email. when i click this field in both or one in the other the result is ever "form-contact", the first form found. How can i really discriminate form-id with same input id element in different forms?

Comment: @almal It's hard to follow your last comment, would you mind creating a _small isolated self contained_ example illustrating your issue? Possible in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with "jquery", here's an answer using jquery:

```
$(elements[x]).parents('form').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when you click on element you can check if is an INPUT, in this case take form_id parent then you can compare inside the loop

```
var elementClicked = e.target.nodeName;
if (elementClicked.toLowerCase() === "input") {
            var formPid = $(elements[x]).parents('form').attr('id');
            ...some code
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `toLowerCase` it, you can check it against `"INPUT"` it's always upper case. Other than that - good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this isn't jQuery, but every `input` element has a `form` attribute which refers back to the `form` element of which it's a child. So you could use...

```
formID = elements[x].form.id
```

...to get the ID of the element's parent form. `button`, `fieldset`, `legend`, `label`, `textarea`, and `select` elements also have this attribute. It's in DOM Level 1, so browser support should be nearly universal.